# Universal way to get stored procedure parameters from different databases

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to add support for PostgreSQL to application which is currently written for MSSQL. In C# I'd like to have "one code for all" wherever possible.

There are bunch of stored procedures, which are rewritten in Postgres as functions.
In the code, to retrieve sp parameters metadata, there used to be ms specific `sp_procedure_params_rowset`.
I changed it to:

```
select p.data_type, p.parameter_name, p.ordinal_position, p.parameter_mode
from information_schema."routines" r 
join information_schema.parameters p on r.specific_name=p.specific_name
where r.routine_schema = 'schema' and r.routine_name = 'procedure_name'
```

This works fine for Postgres, however, for MSSQL the parameter_mode is INOUT for parameters which were set as output.
For example `CREATE PROCEDURE [sp_login] @login varchar(50), @uid int output...` will return

```
varchar @login  1   IN
int     @uid    2   INOUT
```

Now the code is failing for MSSQL, because it is expecting the parameter @uid.

Is there a reason why MSSQL would say in information_schema.parameters INOUT when in fact it is an OUT parameter?

Is there a "universal" way to retrieve the metadata from different databases? Or there's no way around it and I'll have to write some conditions in C#?

Comment: *All* parameters in SQL Server Stored Procedures are IN parameters; they can just be OUT as well. There are no OUT only parameters. As a result, unless a default value for the parameter is defined (in the Procedure's definition) the parameter **must** be supplied.

Comment: Side note, `sp_login` isn't a [documented **S**pecial **P**rocedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-login-transact-sql) and it's not on my 2019 instance. What version of SQL Server are you using to have this **S**pecial **P**rocedure?

Comment: "one code for all" is a pipe-dream. Write code for the DBMS you are using

Comment: Aha, I see. In C# code I was only setting the IN parameter, I guess the rest was automagically set elsewhere.
The 'sp_login' is just an example name I chose here, sorry for confusion.

Comment: You separate your application code from the database with a layer / interface that allows you to implement the functionality your application needs from the implementation required for each database engine you want to support.